# textarea, why does it keep scrolling if height is specified?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove scrolling effect.
With scrolling effect I mean when you select text and it start's scrolling down.

**problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/z7nm8cks/

It shouldn't allow to scroll because I have specified height and text perfectly fits in the area.

If I removed 1 empty line in textare then it worked fine but I need this extra line.

**demo without 1 empty line:** http://jsfiddle.net/3h8rube9/

I hope I was clear enough, not sure how to describe this..

```css
    .content_text {
     text-align: center;
     width: 384px;
     margin-left: 41.28px;
     font-size: 28.8px;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: 40.32px;
    }
    .textarea_dotted {
     font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva', sans-serif;
     height: 322.56px;
     color: black;
     width: 384px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: red url('http://i.imgur.com/CCTWFGo.png');
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     resize: none;
    }
```

```html
    <textarea class="content_text textarea_dotted" disabled>
    Balts sniedziņš snieg uz skujiņām
    Un maigi dziedot pulkstenis skan
    Mirdz šur tur ciemos ugunis
    Un sirds pukst aplaimoti man ...
    
    
    Priecīgus ziemassvētkus!
    </textarea>
```

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to me and it doesn't scroll. What browser are you using? Is there any other CSS applying? Could you add an image with what your browser renders?

Comment: It doesn't scroll for me at all!!!

Comment: Well, if you remove overflow: hidden; then you can clearly see scrollbar and I would like to get rid of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. `overflow: hidden` = **no scrollbar**. Where is the problem? Do you want your content to be "scrollable" without a scrollbar being displayed?

Comment: Yes. If you add overflow: hidden; it's hiding scrollbar but you can still scroll, kind of. You can't scroll with your mouse wheel but if you selec text something like this (http://prntscr.com/9c73ti), from top to the bottom it's scrolling down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Move `</textarea>` up to the same line as your last bit of text.**

Nearly everything contained within a `<textarea>` tag is considered text...that includes returns/line breaks. You have an extra line break at the end. (I also removed the first line break in my snippet below, but it didn't seem to make any difference either way)

```css
.content_text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 384px;
 margin-left: 41.28px;
 font-size: 28.8px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 40.32px;
}
.textarea_dotted {
 font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva', sans-serif;
 height: 322.56px;
 color: black;
 width: 384px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: red url('http://i.imgur.com/CCTWFGo.png');
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="content_text textarea_dotted" disabled>Balts sniedziņš snieg uz skujiņām
Un maigi dziedot pulkstenis skan
Mirdz šur tur ciemos ugunis
Un sirds pukst aplaimoti man ...



Priecīgus ziemassvētkus!</textarea>
```